# How to use Laravel Scout & TNTSearch in combination with relational databases?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-scout

Let's say I have a table 'users' that I want to search with Laravel Scout. It has a lot of attributes, among which the hobby of the user.

- The hobby of the user is not directly placed in the `users` table,
  but by a relational table. So a hobby-id is placed for each user in
  the `users` table.
- Now when I search for `football,` this is not indexed by Laravel
  Scout. Only the id of the hobby `football` is indexed, but that is of
  course not how I want it.

Anyone knows how I can make sure that searching for `football` returns the users that have football as a hobby?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

You have a full control over what exactly is being indexed via [`toSearchableArray()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scout#configuring-searchable-data) so that you can do something along the lines of

```php
class User extends Model
{
    use Searchable;

    // ...

    public function toSearchableArray()
    {
        return array_merge($this->toArray(), [
            'hobby' => $this->hobby === null ? '' : $this->hobby->name;
        ]);
    }

    // ...

    public function hobby()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Hobby::class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Great! That worked with some small edits :). I replaced $u with $this and removed the semi-colon. In my case I replaced it with a comma to able to define more relations in it.
Searched a long time for this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped. :)